# Docker container is shut down immediately unless I change the `mount` `target`

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm trying to start a Docker container with the `mysql` image with a mount pointing to a single database directory (because I don't want all those other databases and log files in my project).

I tried these commands:

```sh
db=test

install -d db-data

docker run \
  -d \
  --rm \
  --mount src=$(pwd)/db-data,target=/var/lib/mysql/$db,type=bind \
  --name $db-db \
    -p 33060:3306 \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=$db \
mysql
```

When I do this, the container starts and terminates immediately. But if I use a target of `target=/var/lib/mysql`, only removing `/$db`, it works, but then this is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

You must not have a mount below /var/lib/mysql in the container. You will have to create a mount for /var/lib/mysql.

This is the error you are facing:

```
0 [ERROR] [MY-010457] [Server] --initialize specified but the data directory has files in it. Aborting.
0 [ERROR] [MY-013236] [Server] The designated data directory /var/lib/mysql/ is unusable. You can remove all files that the server added to it.
0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.26)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

If /var/lib/mysql is not fully populated at startup, the entrypoint will initialize the /var/lib/mysql directory. This will fail, if there are already files in it, which is the case when you mount a file/directory into the data directory.

Answer (score -1):

To be sure that all initialization down on the container, you can add volume after create container.

1. create container without mount:

```
docker run \
  -d \
  --rm \
  --name $db-db \
    -p 33060:3306 \
    -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root \
    -e MYSQL_DATABASE=$db \
mysql
```

2. commit your existing container (that is create a new image from container’s changes):

```
docker commit 5a8f89adeead newcontainername
```

3. run the new container with volume:

```
docker run -ti --mount src=$(pwd)/db-data,target=/var/lib/mysql/$db,type=bind newcontainername /bin/bash
```

4. start the new container (you can find it with docker ps -a) ans stop the old one (already running):

Comment: You should almost never use `docker commit`.  Here it has no effect except to forget the command that's in the original `mysql` image.  In the particular case of the standard Docker Hub database images, it will not preserve data, since that's always stored in a volume (an anonymous volume if you don't explicitly mount something).